# Монетизация в приложениях Android и IOS

Tags: android, ios

Не нашел статьи о том как построен монетизация в приложениях. Хочу узнать о монетизации в Яндексе и в Гугле и стоимость за клик или как там считается, и можно на это зарабатывать?

Если у кого нибудь есть опыт , поделитесь, буду благодарен. Спасибо